# Posso fazer uma pergunta sabendo que ela será fechada?

Tags: debate, perguntas, fechamento

Estava com uma dúvida e pensei em criar uma nova pergunta. Enquanto estava escrevendo notei que ela ficaria ampla demais ou baseada em opinião, então eu desisti de escrevê-la pois sabia que seria fechada. Mas, por outro lado, pensei: "Vou fazer a pergunta assim mesmo. Talvez, mesmo que ela seja fechada, alguém possa respondê-la ou me dar uma luz de por onde começar!".

Vendo por este lado, é correto fazer uma pergunta mesmo sabendo que ela vai ser fechada?

Comment: Já aconteceu um situação parecida comigo e eu recorri ao chat

Comment: Sim você pode, caso sejam várias em sequência é alta a chance do sistema te impor um bloqueio temporário para fazer perguntas. Lembre que você sempre pode pedir alguma opinão no chat seja sobre o problema ou como melhorar a pergunta.

Comment: CaiqueRomero e rray, sim! Já recorri ao chat também diversas vezes para tirar dúvidas. O problema é que a visibilidade no site é maior que no chat, por isso a minha dúvida. Não sabia que o sistema analisava esse tipo de comportamento. Há alguma coisa que o sistema não analisa? :)

Comment: Um caminho possível é abrir uma discussão aqui no meta, incluindo o texto da pergunta, antes de postar no site principal. Aí os outros podem opinar no caso concreto, e até te ajudar a deixar a pergunta menos ampla ou opinativa.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6917/64969; veja a resposta do Renan, tá sensacional

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode, mas dependendo do tipo de atitude que você realiza no site você pode ser:

### Vetado

Quando o veto o que você pode fazer é:

> O único jeito de encerrar um bloqueio de publicação é contribuir positivamente com o site; os vetos automáticos nunca expiram nem "excedem o tempo limite". Comece corrigindo suas publicações existentes; não publique simplesmente a mesma pergunta novamente. Todas as perguntas devem ser úteis também para futuros visitantes, portanto escreva com gramática e ortografia corretas, formatando sua publicação de modo que possa ser lida facilmente e fornecendo todos os detalhes possíveis sobre seu problema e o que você já tentou. A leitura da sua pergunta em voz alta para si mesmo pode ajudar a entender como ela soa para os outros.

---

Agora como uma opinião e adendo, pense que se a pergunta tem motivos para ser fechada e mesmo que ajude ao AP fazer para obter alguma opinião/sugestão ainda sim para o site isso será ruim, pois este não é o foco do site (escopo).

Então se você pensar na comunidade e na utilidade futura da pergunta notara que perguntas assim não agregam em nada, apensar de não ser um grande problema (pois será fechada provavelmente) ainda sim seria melhor se for:

- **Ampla**

  Dividia em diferentes perguntas, se mantendo atento ao escopo do site
- **Baseada em opiniões**

  Pode procurar o chat principal do site e talvez alguém possa sugerir por experiencia um caminho: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Comment: Kudos pela sugestão de perguntar no chat