# Como perguntar no meta sobre como fazer a pergunta X no Stack Overflow em português?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, meta

Na pergunta [Posso fazer uma pergunta sabendo que ela será fechada?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6914/64969), o autor questiona hipoteticamente se valeria a pena fazer uma pergunta fadada ao fechamento. Uma das sugestões foi [esta do @bfavaretto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6914/posso-fazer-uma-pergunta-sabendo-que-ela-ser%c3%a1-fechada#comment26651_6914):

> Um caminho possível é abrir uma discussão aqui no meta, incluindo o texto da pergunta, antes de postar no site principal. Aí os outros podem opinar no caso concreto, e até te ajudar a deixar a pergunta menos ampla ou opinativa.

Então, eu pergunto:

Como devemos iniciar uma discussão no meta sobre uma pergunta possivelmente ampla/baseada em opiniões?

Para um caso concreto, como eu poderia fazer para abrir no meta a discussão sobre [o problema das 8 rainhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285412/64969). A intenção não é obter a resposta a como fazer essa pergunta, mas como seria fazer a pergunta sobre como fazer essa pergunta...

Comment: Isto aqui é uma meta-pergunta que a resposta é uma pergunta

Comment: Foi mal fiquei bugado um pouco aqui com esta pergunta sua xD. O que exatamente você quer saber em relação a **pergunta**?

Comment: @gato, como eu faço uma pergunta no meta para saber como fazer a pergunta no SOpt. Eu espero que a resposta a esta publicação contenha um exemplo de como fazer essa pergunta para suscitar o debate sobre como fazer a pergunta das 8 rainhas.

Comment: Parafrasear o que [escrevi no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43550863#43550863): esta pergunta é uma pergunta de como realizar perguntas para fazer perguntas

Comment: Eu desconheço o tema da pergunta citada, para mim é dificil dizer como você poderia fazer a pergunta. No geral, eu costumo fornecer um contexto e ilustrar uma situação, é claro que eu tenho que ficar atento com o nível de abrangência da pergunta para que não fique ampla demais. Também deixo mais restrita a pergunta, mesmo que ela seja um pouco subjetiva, assim eu consigo garantir uma resposta menos opinativa e mais focada no problema da pergunta. Por fim, na hora que estou fazendo a pergunta, eu tento me colocar no lugar de quem for responder desta forma eu garanto uma pergunta respondível.

Comment: Sua meta-pergunta está ampla demais! :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, pensei em como perguntar sobre como fazer perguntas no meta sobre como fazer perguntas para fazer perguntas no SOpt xD

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acabei de fazer uma pergunta sobre o tema desta pergunta abordada, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/285871/27190). Hoje o professor estava falando a respeito deste problema na faculdade ;)

Comment: @gato acabou com o caso de teste, kkkk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como devemos iniciar uma discussão no meta sobre uma pergunta possivelmente ampla/baseada em opiniões?

Existe um provérbio iugoslavo que diz: *"fale o que tem que falar e saia correndo"* :D

Brincadeiras à parte... Não há nada errado em ser direto, sincero e honesto. Acredito que seguir essa ideia fará com que a dúvida seja tratada com mais carinho do que se fizermos rodeios. Uma boa forma seria:

> Tenho uma dúvida, porém no momento só consigo expressá-la de forma que atraia respostas baseadas em opiniões, ou muito amplas.
>
> Meu problema é que eu preciso determinar, programaticamente, quando o Palmeiras ganhará seu primeiro mundial.
>
> Acredito que isso é baseado em opiniões, pois o time de qualquer respondedor poderá pesar em sua resposta. Além disso, desconheço metodologias com as quais a data poderia ser calculada, o que faria com que a exposição de todas as formas possíveis pudesse ser ampla demais.
>
> Acho também que receberia votos negativos por motivo de "não demonstrar esforço de pesquisa", uma vez que para muitos já é dado como tautologia que o Palmeiras jamais terá um mundial.
>
> Como posso tornar minha pergunta mais objetiva, e adequá-la ao formato do site?

Daí, alguém poderia responder o seguinte:

> Você precisa montar um mapa de calor com as probabilidades de cada time ganhar uma partida, e fazer um cruzamento dessas probabilidades jogo a jogo. Utilize campeonatos anteriores como base e treine uma inteligência artificial para encontrar um padrão. Você obterá as chances de ganho de mundial por campeonato, e aí é só questão de estatística. Por exemplo, se as chances atuais forem de 25% ao ano, é de se esperar que o Palmeiras ganhe um mundial em até quatro anos.

Com base em uma resposta dessas, o OP poderia então perguntar:

> **Como determinar as chances de ganho de campeonato para um time de um desporto qualquer?**
>
> Preciso treinar uma inteligência artificial para utilizar mapas de probabilidades de vitória em jogo com score na determinação das chances de um time qualquer ser campeão após uma série de rodadas. Como posso fazer isso?
>
> [machine-learning](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) [prolog](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog)

Como disse o saudoso Stephen Hawkings: tudo que precisamos fazer é continuar a conversar. Se nos comunicarmos bem por aqui, o índice de perguntas fechadas e negativadas pode cair bastante.