# O que é uma pergunta "exceção"?

Tags: debate

Inicio esse questionamento pelo simples fato de criar algumas perguntas no SOpt e não entender muito bem o porquê que elas são fechadas. Antes de criar uma pergunta eu analiso alguns pontos simples:

- A pergunta já existe?
- Está dentro de *on-topic*?
- Há discussões semelhantes sobre o assunto da pergunta no meta?

Por fim, encontro perguntas significativamente relevantes que inclusive receberam altíssimos votos e respostas que poderiam preencher umas 5 páginas de um livro, algumas até foram discutidas no meta. Então, depois dessa análise simples e algumas vezes encontrando discussões concretas que permitem eu fazer a pergunta, eu a faço. E então, *Voilà!*, ela é fechada. Os argumentos quase sempre são:

- "Essa pergunta é muito ampla".
- "Existem perguntas parecidas, mas são exceções".
- "Algumas perguntas foram permitidas por serem antigas".
- "Sua pergunta pode ser parecidas com outras, mas as outras foram aceitas pela comunidade".

. Vou citar alguns exemplos:

- [**As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar/2709#2709) - Quase certeza que se eu postar uma pergunta como *"As mensagens de boas-vindas devem ser formais?"* ela vai ser fechada.
- [**Como funciona o licenciamento de software no Brasil?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-de-software-no-brasil) - Fiz uma pergunta que recebeu diversos [votos de fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292124/um-software-pode-mudar-de-licen%C3%A7a). Não entendo qual a diferença da minha para esta. Inclusive a resposta para ela é um *wiki*. Porque a minha não pode ser também?
- [**Como funciona o licenciamento dos programas Open-Source?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29789/como-funciona-o-licenciamento-dos-programas-open-source) - Um pouco mais sobre "licenciamentos".
- [**Como é feito um compilador?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104814/como-%C3%A9-feito-um-compilador/104818#104818) - Uma vez perguntei assim: *"Como percorrer os bytes de um QRCode?"*, onde queria saber como funcionava uma biblioteca de leitura. Fecharam como "ampla demais". Essa pergunta, se feita nos dias de hoje, não seria "ampla demais" também?
- [**Algoritmo para detectar nudez com boa precisão?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104656/algoritmo-para-detectar-nudez-com-boa-precis%C3%A3o) - Acho que essa também é tão ampla quanto percorrer os bytes de um QRCode...

Eu poderia citar mais outros exemplos e sei que o pessoal que já tem um bom tempo aqui no meta sabe que existem mais perguntas neste contexto.

Concluindo, o que faz uma pergunta ser uma **exceção**?

Comment: Mostre casos onde fala em exceção para vermos o contexto do seu uso.

Comment: @bio se olhar o histórico dessa do licenciamento, vai notar que o autor publicou pergunta e resposta, e ainda fez um quadro no começo da resposta explicando o contexto. Ficou complicada essa questão sua, pois cada caso mencionado na sua lista é uma história completamente diferente. Uma característica da exceção é... ser exceção. Se tivesse uma regra definindo já não seria exceção. No máximo um "caso especial".

Comment: @Maniero, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292124/um-software-pode-mudar-de-licen%C3%A7a

Comment: @Maniero, nem sempre são definidas como "exceção", como explicitei em "os argumentos quase sempre são". Vai ser difícil eu achar essas definições, afinal, o contexto não se trata de algo recente e englobei diversas situações.

Comment: Parece, agora, que até minha pergunta no meta está ampla demais? :(

Comment: @Bacco, mas [há uma regra](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2691/5043) para licenciamentos, não? Seria então um "caso especial"?

Comment: Não há regra, houve uma opinião positiva de algumas pessoas nesse post específico. Se você olhar vários outros sobre o tema no meta vai ver que isso não é consenso (pelo contrário). Notando as datas dos posts, vai ver que esse caso que vc pegou é "antigo" quando as coisas ainda estavam meio nebulosas.

Comment: No próprio [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5488#5488) a indicação é oposta

Comment: Não acho que seja caso de exceção, é caso de pergunta bem feita, que permite ser respondida dentro das regras. Eu acho que o Bacco quis dizer ali foi que algumas passam apesar de existir a regra, e o fato de passar não significa que virou regra. De forma geral acho que você está falando de perguntas que tiveram uma forma que dava pra produzir algo útil. Talvez, além de ampla, a pergunta seja XY. **Talvez** em outra forma a sua pergunta passasse. Jurídico é complicado para passar, precisa estar muito bem adequada para ser útil aqui. As vezes uma mudança de palavras já ajuda.

Comment: Talvez a pergunta só esteja confusa demais, talvez falte mais contexto.

Comment: @Maniero, o que devo fazer nestes casos? Sair em busca da perfeição com edições atrás de edições pra tentar salvar minha pergunta? Toda vez que fechar uma pergunta devo vir ao meta e *lutar* para que ela seja reaberta? E se eu não sei fazer uma "pergunta bem feita"? Ela morre?...

Comment: @Bacco, há uma contradição por parte da própria comunidade? Ainda bem que abri essa questão aqui, poderíamos voltar à esse debate como [você já o fez](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2689/dúvida-sobre-licenças-para-software-livre-é-off-topic-no-so-em-português).

Comment: Basicamente é isto. Senão o que a comunidade deve fazer? Deixar todo tipo de pergunta ser feita e não importa que resultado dê? Agora parece certo que a pergunta é XY. E comunidade é contraditória, costuma ocorrer em todo lugar com mais de uma pessoa. Note que falar de licença não é *off-topic*, mas tem maneiras que fazer isto. Se a sua pergunta aqui no meta fosse sobre a sua pergunta fechada, poderíamos discutir o que ela tem de errado, mas você perguntou o que é uma exceção.

Comment: @Maniero, então parece que as [recomendações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) não adiantam muita coisa, talvez eu esteja entendendo errado. Esse foi um dos motivos que eu abri [essa outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6914/posso-fazer-uma-pergunta-sabendo-que-ela-será-fechada) também. Enfim, perguntei sobre o que é uma exceção e contextualizei alguns exemplos. Poderia formular uma resposta sobre tais?

Comment: Leia com atenção os dois *links*, eles mostram porque a pergunta não foi bem aceita. Não posso responder porque sequer entendo o que está sendo perguntado. Na verdade entendo, e não é o que está escrito. Se fosse isso eu não saberia responder, é como perguntar o que faz algo entrar na moda.

Comment: @Maniero, crio uma pergunta pra cada exemplo? Caramba, parece que eu não sei perguntar mesmo... Desculpa o desabafo, mas tá complicado... :(